# help with explicit template especialization

Tags: c++, templates

thank you for looking
i got this example from my book but i cant understand why the line

```
  S<void,int>  sv;  // uses Template at (2)
```

but

```
S<void,char> e2;   
//uses (1) when im thinking it would use (2) especialization as well
```

could anyone explain the behavior? 
btw all the comments in code below are from book author

thank you very much!

```
template<typename T> 
class Types { 
  public: 
    typedef int I; 
}; 

template<typename T, typename U = typename Types<T>::I> 
class S;                        // (1) 

template<> 
class S<void> {                 // (2) 
  public: 
    void f(); 
}; 

template<> class S<char, char> {}; // (3) 

template<> class S<char, 0>;    // ERROR: 0 cannot substitute U 

int main() 
{ 
    S<int>*      pi;   // OK: uses (1), no definition needed 
    S<int>       e1;   // ERROR: uses (1), but no definition available 
    S<void>*     pv;   // OK: uses (2) 
    S<void,int>  sv;   // OK: uses (2), definition available 
    S<void,char> e2;   // OK: uses (1), definition available 
    S<char,char> e3;   // ERROR: uses (3), but no definition available 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should it use `(2)`?

(2) is a specialization of `S<void, int>`. What you have is `S<void, char>`. The types are different, so the specialization isn't used. Specializations only apply if they match *exactly*. It's not good enough that "a char can be implicitly promoted to an int". If no specialization exists for `S<void, char>`, then it will use the general, nonspecialized version.

Comment: but there isnt specialization for S<void, int> either
i Only see especialization for S<void> and <char, char> {}
and 
S<void,int>  sv; 
uses S<void>

Comment: o i just saw now that is implicitly a
S<void,int> cause of the default argument in General template
sorry i missed im a noobie
thanks alot! i see clear it now